# Is Clairaut's Equation linear or nonlinear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation of form 
$$
y=xy' + f(y')
$$
where $y$ is a function of $x$ is the Clairaut equation. Linear? Nonlinear?

Answer (score 0):

Formally speaking, linearity/non-linearity depends upon $f$. However, if the differential equation is linear then we can treat it as a first order first degree equation and hence it is always solvable. So the non-trivial part is when Clairaut's differential equation is non-linear.

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion: The word "it" is used five times to refer variously to "the answer to the OP's question", "the function $f$", and "the Clairaut differential equation". Using the appropriate noun in each instance would make this response more useful to the OP, and to posterity.

Comment: So what must the function $f$ be so that it is linear/nonlinear? specifics?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang... Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to improve the presentation.

Comment: @M98B-PRO... If $f(x)$ is of the form $ax+b$, it is linear. Otherwise it is non-linear.